# Подскажите программу для копирования разработки на сервер

Tags: веб-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста программу под WN для копирования разработки с локального сервера на сервер по FTP, автоматически. Чтобы можно было разработку вести на localhost и все дублировалось на сервер.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN, git и другие **системы контроля версий**

Answer (score 0):

Webstorm/phpstorm
Deployment ->  configuration -> autoupload